# My constructors are initializing with the same, seemingly random incorrect values

Tags: c++, list, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am writing a program that replicates the functionality of the List ADT using arrays; I am beginning by creating a Node object with two attributes: the element and a pointer to the next node. When I run my code, however, it reports that all of my Nodes initialize with element -2 and a random pointer, regardless of how I construct them; does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* Class Name: Node
Main Function: Store an element (in this case, a positive integer) and a pointer to the next Node in the List, or to "null" 
Methods: getElement, setElement, getNext, setNext

*/

class Node {
    public:
        int element; //Node has two attributes: an integer, element, and a pointer to a Node, next
        Node* next;
        
        Node(int element, Node* next){ //Node can be constructed with both attributes inputted
            this->element = element;
            this->next = next;
        }
        
        Node (int element){ //If only one is inputted, then
            this->element = element;
            next = nullptr; //the "next" pointer is initialized as "NULL"
        }
        
        Node (Node* next){
            element = 0; //or the node is initialized with an element of "0"
            this-> next = next;
        }
        
        Node(){
            int element = 0; //the Node can also be constructed given no input, using both default values
            Node* next = nullptr; 
        }
            
        
        /* Method Name: getElement
        Input Parameters: N/A
        Return Values: element, the value stored by the node
        Main Function: Returns the element stored by the node
        
        */
        
        int getElement() {
            return element;
        }
        
        /* Method Name: setElement
        Input Parameters: A new element to store in the Node
        Return Values: the original element being stored, if the method executes correctly; -1, if method encounters an error
        Main Function: Sets the node's element to a new value after checking if it is positive
        
        */
        
        int setElement (int newElement){
            if (newElement <= 0){
                cerr << "Error: this List can only store positive integers." << endl << endl;
                return -1;
            }
            int oldElement = element;
            element = newElement;
            return oldElement;
        }
        
        /* Method Name: getNext
        Input Parameters: N/A
        Return Values: next, a pointer to the next Node in the List
        Main Function: Reads a file and stores its contents as an array of integers; reports if an error occurs
        
        */
        
        Node* getNext() {
            return next;
        }
        
        /* Method Name: setNext
        Input Parameters: A new pointer for the Node to direct to
        Return Values: the original pointer being stored, if the method executes correctly; -1, if method encounters an error
        Main Function: Sets the node's element to a new value after checking that the node it points to exists
        
        */
        
        Node* setNext (Node* newNext){
            Node* oldNext = next;
            next = newNext;
            return oldNext;
        }
        
        
};


int main(){
    
    Node n1; //tests if a Node can be constructed given no input
    cout << "When a node is constructed with no input, it has an element of " << n1.getElement() << " and a next of " << n1.getNext() << endl << endl;
    
    
    Node n2 (5); //tests if a Node can be constructed given an element as input
    cout << "When a node is constructed with element 5, it has an element of " << n2.getElement() << " and a next of " << n2.getNext() << endl << endl;
    
    
    Node n3 (&n1); //tests if a Node can be constructed given an address as input
    cout << "When a node is constructed pointing to Node 1, it has an element of " << n3.getElement() << " and a next of " << n3.getNext(); 
    cout << ", which points to " << n3.getNext()->getElement() << endl << endl;
    
    
    Node n4 (10, &n2); //tests if a Node can be constructed given an element and an address as unput
    cout << "When a node is constructed with element 10 pointing to Node 2, it has an element of " << n4.getElement() << " and a next of " << n4.getNext(); 
    cout << ", which points to " << n4.getNext()->getElement() << endl << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the program to construct four nodes: one with element 0 and a nullptr, one with element 5 and a null pointer, one with element 0 pointing to node 1 and one with element 10 pointing to node 2.

Comment: I apologize for the poor formatting of the code; this is my first post on the site.

Comment: Please enable your compiler warnings. [My compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/5Te9eE4sq) immediately told me about unused variables in the default constructor.

Comment: *"all of my Nodes initialize with element -2 and a random pointer"* -- Could you share your actual output in addition to this summary? When I ran your code, I did not see `-2`, and only one of the pointers was random/arbitrary. (Plus, looking at the code, only the default-constructed one should have random/unexpected values.) Is your result from the original version of the code in this question, where you displayed `n1` four times instead of looking at each of the nodes?

Comment: The default constructor `Node()` leaves the two members uninitialized. Instead, it declares and initializes two local variables that happen to have the same names; but doesn't use those local variables.

Comment: Using [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) would have avoided this mistake completely, and created more readable code.

Comment: Incidentally, "the same, seemingly random incorrect values" may be what you are seeing in your testing, but is not a correct description in general.  The behaviour (due to printing value of uninitialised members of an object) is undefined, so the values seen (if any) may change with phase of the moon, compiler options, compiler updates, presence of a cat on your keyboard,  etc, etc.